# POSTGRESQL Subtract to each row the previous row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I'm writting a function which at some step I have query result like the following one:

| timestamp | Consumed Fuel | Processed Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-09-2021 5:00:00 | 3000000 | 982135 |
| 23-09-2021 6:00:00 | 3000010 | 982136 |
| 23-09-2021 7:00:00 | 3000030 | 982137 |
| 23-09-2021 8:00:00 | 3000032 | 982152 |

And I have to translate it to this:

| timestamp | Consumed Fuel | Processed Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23-09-2021 5:00:00 | 10 | 1 |
| 23-09-2021 6:00:00 | 20 | 2 |
| 23-09-2021 7:00:00 | 2 | 15 |

With one row less, and translating the cumulated values to some sort of "rate", subtracting to each row the previous one and labeling it with the previous timestamp. How I could achieve this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html)s in PostgreSQL docs.

**lead** ( value anyelement [, offset integer [, default anyelement ]] ) → anyelement

> Returns value evaluated at the row that is offset rows after the current row within the partition; if there is no such row, instead returns default (which must be of the same type as value). Both offset and default are evaluated with respect to the current row. If omitted, offset defaults to 1 and default to NULL.

```
SELECT
  tm,
  LEAD(ConsumedFuel) OVER (ORDER BY tm) - ConsumedFuel AS ConsumedFueld,
  LEAD(ProcessedVolume) OVER (ORDER BY tm) - ProcessedVolume AS ProcessedVolume
FROM
  t
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=33276ee48e301f7c4f6ecbdcb0c1a993)*

Comment: Seems nice, thanks. Would be possible to discard last row?

Comment: LEAD function is not allowed in WHERE clause. You could add it as subquery. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=82393497e3424e09c3fbd7c3e46f5b0b

Comment: I've been tinkering and wouldn't `ORDER BY tm DESC OFFSET 1` and then `ORDER BY tm ASC` be more consistent?

Comment: Can you add a dbfiddle link please?

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=393c6098cfefac0124f5b918e6d0a5be)

Comment: Your [result makes no sense](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9ae6b1bdd0e028c8f1b5032d9dd05b55)! `2` as consumed fuel for 07:00 is the **future** consumption (i.e. between 07:00 and 08:00) - it would be better (IMHO) to have 2 & 15 at 08:00 for the results for the past hour? As for performance, it appears that your `OFFSET` is the more performant, but only if you remove the (unnecessary) outer query! The last query in the snippet also sorts the results in `ASC` order.

Comment: No, for me makes all the sense. It's all the consumed meanwhile 7 was on the clock. Think about days, the consumed fuel for 23/06/2020 (2020-06-23 00:00:00) would be the consumed fuel from the same 2020-06-23 00:00:00 to the future 2020-06-23 23:59:59. Therefore, the correct query I think it would be [this one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=318e3f4394f162b77d2c7cf7ebfd9de4)